# Cypress is not rendering the page correctly in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cypress

I have been writing Cypress automation tests for a project and I have noticed when watching the tests back that they are rendering one page over the top of the other. You will see in the screenshot that the previous page is still slightly visible in the back ground, so then when I try and find an element it will find the one on the previous page as it think it 'exists' when it doesn't on this page I am interacting with.

So the first image is the page I am testing, which is rendered correctly.
[image: Correctly rendered]

Once I click on the checkbox for 'Merchant' it scrolls down the page automatically and this is when it renders the previous page, you will see it highlighted in red. This does not happen at all when manual testing, only when using Cypress.

We having built this webapp in React using Mui. Any ideas why this is happening? Its like its rendering the previous page when I scroll down (it uses the same URL). I have tried changing the Viewport settings thinking this could have been the issue but it didn't resolve it.

[image: Incorrectly rendered]

The code is very basic, it is.

```js
it('User can add and remove a merchant', () => {
      cy.get('[data-testid="New Email"]').click()
      cy.get('#subject').type('Automation' + id)
      cy.get('[role="textbox"]').type('This is dummy text for automation tests')
      cy.get('[data-testid="attachments-upload"]').attachFile('pdftest.pdf')
      
      // Check the Send Email is still disabled
      cy.get('[data-testid="modal-button-Send Email"]').should('be.disabled')
      // Add a merchant as a recipient by checking the checkbox
      cy.get('[value="merchant"]').click()
      cy.contains('button', 'Select Merchant').click() // Here is when the error happens
      cy.contains('aaa@gmail.com').click()
      cy.contains('button', 'Submit').click()
      
      // Remove the merchant
      cy.get('[data-testid="RemoveCircleIcon"]').eq(1).click()
    })
```

Comment: You need to paste the code where you do the click on `Merchant`

Comment: Hmm.. Could you also add the error output screenshot or c/p error? Also, could you paste some html of that button as well as the whole spec file code? Seems we need to dig deeper into the issue

Answer (score 0):

Material UI has animations for every action. Perhaps the test is ending too soon, and you caught the screen mid-animation.

Try adding a final assertion like

```js
cy.contains('This is dummy text for automation tests')
  .should('not.be.visible')
```

Or

```js
cy.contains('This is dummy text for automation tests')
  .should('not.exist')
```

Comment: Nice! I really hope if it will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think so, the error occurs well before the end of the test. I initially though it happened on the last line.

Comment: Hi @TesterDick thanks for the answer but you are right the error occurs well before the end of the test so this will not resolve the issue. It happens through the whole website, this was just an example of an area I could share. If anything else is needed I can provide it if it helps but this issue has been happening for a while and until now I've had work arounds to get past it, but the time has come for it to be investigated in more detail and fixed.

Comment: Since it's React, if the component is hooks-based try adding `cy.wait(0)` after the click action. Sometimes Cypress does not release the thread and hooks cannot complete an action.

Comment: Other than that, if you have a repo I can take a look at it.